# How do I get first item from CakePHP 3 results object

Tags: php, object, cakephp, resultset, cakephp-3.0

**TLDR:**  How do I use the first item in a results object?

---

After getting data from the database, I want to pull the first one out and use it separately before repeating through the remaining videos. (All in my template/view file).  If it were an array, I could use something like `array_shift`, but so far with the object, I'm coming up empty.

First, I get the data in my Controller, and pass it to the View:

```
$videos = $this->Videos->find();
$this->set(compact('videos'));
```

Then, in the View (template file), **I've tried this:**

```
$featuredVideo = $videos{0};
```

> Error Cannot use object of type Cake\ORM\Query as array

**And this:**

```
$featuredVideo = $videos->0;
```

> Error: syntax error, unexpected '0' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

**And this:**

```
$featuredVideo = $videos->toArray()[0];
```

This works (kind of), but then I have to use `$featuredVideo` as an Array, which is different to everywhere else, and seems non-elegant.

**And this:**

```
$featuredVideo = $videos->first();
```

This is awesome, but it limits the entire object to only the first, so I no longer have the rest of the videos.

**And this:**

```
$allVideos = $videos;
$featuredVideo = $videos->first();
```

But, apparently since it's an object, the `$allVideos` is just a reference to the `$videos`, because they both get reduced to the first video.

I realize this seems like a simple question, and it's likely a simple answer, but I have looked around, and tried the suggestions on how to get the first item from an object with the above results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What I failed to understand was that `->find()` just returns the query object until you tell it to execute via an `->all()` or a `->first()` or by running it through a `foreach()` loop.

So, I couldn't just access the first child object, since the query hadn't yet executed to show the results.

And when I was trying to do `->first()` after setting the variable above it, it was actually executing the query on the query object after setting limit to 1, hence making both only have 1.

More [details here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-rows-from-a-table).

The answer (in code):

```
// Controller
$videos = $this->Videos->find()->all();
$this->set(compact('videos'));

// View
$featuredVideo = $videos->first();
```

More details here about [when query objects are lazily evaluated](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#how-are-queries-lazily-evaluated).

---

Thanks jose_zap and marc_ for helping clarify this one for me.